# Register Session Error (null)

Tags: php

Problem :
After login, it redirect to index.php not home.php.
From my observation, session register for both is NULL.
Can someone help me?
I'm new with PhP.

Thanks, sorry for bad grammar/english.

Check login :

```
<?php ob_start();
include ("connect/db.php");
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$username' and passwd='$password'";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)){
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$member = $rows['member_id'];
$_SESSION["iduser"] = $username;
$_SESSION["idmember"] = $member;
echo '<center>Login Successfull!<br>Username : <i>' .$_SESSION["iduser"]. ' [' .$_SESSION["idmember"]. ']</i><br><br>';
echo "<input class='button' type='button' value='Enter' onClick=\"javascript:window.location.href='home.php'\"></center>";
}

else {
echo '<center>Login Error!<br>Invalid Username or Password.<br><br>';
echo "<input class='button' type='button' value='Back' onClick=\"javascript:window.location.href='index.php'\"></center>";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Home :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['member'])){
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['iduser'];
$member = $_SESSION['idmember'];
?>
```

Comment: Try starting the session in the login, not on your home page. I'm assuming your entry point is at 'Check Login'

Comment: `session_start()` must be in all documents at the start, and don't use `mysql_*` functions because are deprecated and will be removed, start using `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: Use session start in the Check login  page also at the top as you did in home. Only if session is invoked, you can save values to session. Also avoid using deprecated mysql , try mysqli instead

Comment: off topic : 
why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`? You should not allow ` ' or " ` in username. And for password you can hash or encrypt first before inserting into database, So you won't be needing `mysql_real_escape_string` 
btw mysql_* are deprecated, try to switch on mysqli_* or PDO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page Check Login, add session_start() at the top as in page - Home.

In the page Home, line

`if(!isset($_SESSION['member'])){`

should be

`if(!isset($_SESSION['idmember'])){`

Comment: thanks, its very helpful. Finally i can continue my assignment T.T

Answer (score 0):

Do you have started session on your first script with `session_start();` ?

$_SESSION isset but is empty so into home try with : var_dump(!empty($_SESSION[val]));

If you did, you should try to add some `var_dump(expression);` in order to see where is the problem, for exemple to verify your sql result.